# basic_string proprietary allocator

Tags: c++, stdstring

I am evaluating to use the basic_string template to implement a string like object to be allocated using an external memory manager.
That memory manager, keeps the size of the maximum size of the memory allocated and the current size (allowing for that current size to increase up to the maximum one).
In order to avoid redundance I would like to make use of that data for the string.

Does any body knows if it is possible and where to look for detailed instructions ?
I already know that it is possible to give a propierary allocator, but nothing more.

Comment: What do you mean by memory manager? Do you mean a custom allocator?

Comment: you may think it like that

Answer (score 3):

It is possible, for sure. Just provide a custom allocator which implements the std::allocator (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/allocator/) interface.

Then:

```
typedef std::basic_string<
    char, std::char_traits<char>, custom_allocator<char> >
    custom_string;
```

But be warned, this string is incompatible to std::string and you might have to implement the conversions custom_string <-> std::string.

Comment: The problem is not when I have just to use a custom allocator, but when some part of the data managed by it should be used instead of the data defined by basic_string. I mean the current and maximum size.

Answer (score 1):

It can look like that:

```
template<class T>
struct CustomAllocator: std::allocator<T> {
  template<class U>
  struct rebind {
    typedef CustomAllocator<U> other;
  };
};

typedef std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, CustomAllocator<char>> CustomString;
```

Now `CustomString` uses your `CustomAllocator` instead of `std::allocator`.
To change the way the memory is actually allocated, your can define custom `allocate` and `deallocate`(and probably some other)methods inside the `CustomAllocator` class(and add all the required logic for it).

Comment: N.B. "override" is the wrong word (in C++ that is used in the context of virtual member functions, so using it for a different meaning is confusing)

Comment: The problem is not when I have just to use a custom allocator, but when some part of the data managed by it should be used instead of the data defined by basic_string. I mean the current and maximum size. –